# How to insert multiple file (pdf,excel sheets,etc) into database using java?

Tags: java

I did this for single file but for multiple it's showing error. Please let me know the complete code if possible for "Insertion and storing of multiple files into database" (mysql,putty).

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Can u show your code what u have done untill now?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  You will get better results that way.